# iPhone - How to get time zone offset?

Tags: iphone, nstimezone

We have NSTimeZone class that tells more about the time zone.
But I want to get only the offset of the time. For example: +05.30 is offset for Inida
In other words offset of time with reference to UTC.

One problem with following code is that it crashes with 4.3 simulator and works fine with 4.2 simulator. Because 4.2 simulator is giving output with reference to GMT and 4.3 simulator with reference to IST

```
NSString* tzDescription = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] description];
NSArray* tzArray = [tzDescription componentsSeparatedByString:@"GMT"];
NSString* gmtStr = [[tzArray objectAtIndex:1] substringToIndex:6];
```

I couldn't find a solution that is generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use NSDate and NSDateFormatter class to get the time zone offset. You can do it in following way.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]
initWithDateFormat:@"zzz" allowNaturalLanguage:NO];
NSString *zoneOffset = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

So in zoneOffset now you will be having your required thing.

Comment: nice. don't forget to release dateFormat when not in ARC.